# Why is my ajax clock not grabbing the server's time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am implementing an ajax clock that should be getting the time on my server. I have US/pacific time. But my clock won't grab the time of the server and seems to show a random time. I can't figure out why.

This is my script for the time on client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var start_time;
                var current_time;

                //gets current server time
                var get_time = function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '../Server_Side/clock.php',
                        data: ({ action : 'get_time' }),
                        success: (function (data) {
                            start_time = new Date(
                                data.year,
                                data.month,
                                data.day,
                                data.hour,
                                data.minute,
                                data.second
                           //comment
                            );
                            $('#clock').html(current_time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {timeZone:'America/Vancouver'}));
                        }),
                        dataType: 'json'
                    });
                }

                //counts 0.25s
                var cnt_time = function () {
                    current_time = new Date(start_time.getTime() + 250);
                    $('#clock').html(current_time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {timeZone:'America/Vancouver'}));
                    start_time = current_time;
                }

                setInterval(cnt_time, 250); //add 250ms to current time every 250ms
                setInterval(get_time, 30250); //sync with server every 30,25 second
                get_time();
            </script>
```

And this is what I have for the Server side for the clock:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'get_time' ) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode (
        array (
              'year' => date('Y'),
                'month' => date('m'),
                'day' => date('d'),
                'hour' => date('h'),
                'minute' => date('i'),
                'second' => date('s')
            )
        );
    }
else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    echo '<h1>404 Not Found</h1>';
    echo '<p>The page that you have requested could not be found.</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: do you have any errors on the console?

Comment: Makes rather little sense to have PHP spit out year, month, date, etc. as individual values. I would simply output the current timestamp - that times 1,000 can be used directly as parameter for the Date constructor. And re-checking the time with the server every 30.25 seconds doesn’t make that much sense, either - do you expect the seconds on my machine to be significantly slower or faster than on your server …? Now setTimeout might not make your code run exactly “on the millisecond”, but correcting for that should happen on the client side, no need to bother the server again.

Comment: the main delay will be the HTTP response time from server, could take seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`date('m')` will return `01` till `12`. You might want `date('n') - 1`, which returns 0 to 11. For JS Date object, the second parameter accepts `monthIndex`, which accepts 0 (Jan) to 11 (Dec) only.

References:

- JS Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
- PHP date(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: What I mean is that the hour, minute, and seconds do not match with the current hour, minute, and seconds of the server. Almost like its randomly grabbing a time from a separate server somewhere else

Comment: You can check the server response in Developer Console, to see whether your PHP is responding correctly.